# combine js array's

Tags: javascript

pretty simple question, can't quite fig. it out.

I have 2 js array's that I need to combine into a new array, based on sub_key.

```
var items = [
    Object { 
        OBJECTID=1,
        Name="COMMAND B", 
        ID="AR0xx",
        sub_key="1000"
        },
    Object {
        OBJECTID=2, 
        Name="95TH PCT", 
        ID="AR0xx",
        sub_key="1001"
        },
   Object { 
        OBJECTID=379, 
        Name="dummy4", 
        ID="AR0xx",
        sub_key="9999"
        }
   ];

var subitems = [
   Object { 
       OBJECTID=787, 
       ID="AR0xx", 
       sub_key=1000, 
       Long_Name = foo
       }, 
   Object { 
       OBJECTID=789, 
       ID="AR0xx", 
       sub_key=1001, 
       Long_Name = "bar"
       }, 
   Object { 
       OBJECTID=1, 
       ID="AR0xx", 
       sub_key=1001, 
       Long_Name="baz"
       }, 
   Object { 
       OBJECTID=788,
       ID="AR0xx", 
       sub_key=1001,
       Long_Name="buzzz"
       }
   ];
```

I'd like to create an array like so, which just combines the above 2, based on sub_key

```
var data = [
    COMMAND B=["foo"],
    95TH PCT=["bar","baz","buzz"]
    dummy4=[]
    ];
```

Here's what I tried but it doesn't work... i think i'm close?? thanks for any help!

```
data = [];
for (var key in items){
    var o = items[key];
    //data.push(o.Name);
    for (var subkey in subitems){
        subo = subitems[subkey];
        if (o.sub_key == subo.sub_key){
            data[o.Name].push(subo.Long_Name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not even remotely valid JS syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up your script, here is what you are trying to do. It craetes an array of objects using the Name from items and matching sub_key from sub_items.

```
var items = [
  { OBJECTID: 1, 
    Name: 'COMMAND B', 
    ID: 'AR0xx', 
    sub_key: '1000' 
  }, 
  { OBJECTID: 2, 
    Name: '95TH PCT', 
    ID: 'AR0xx', 
    sub_key: '1001' 
  }, 
  { OBJECTID: 379, 
    Name: 'dummy4', 
    ID: 'AR0xx', 
    sub_key: '9999' 
  } 
]; 

var subitems = [ 
  { BJECTID: 787,
    ID: 'AR0xx', 
    sub_key: '1000', 
    Long_Name: 'foo' 
  }, 
  { OBJECTID: '789', 
    ID: 'AR0xx', 
    sub_key: '1001', 
    Long_Name: 'bar' 
  }, 
  { OBJECTID: '1', 
    ID: 'AR0xx', 
    sub_key: 1001, 
    Long_Name: 'baz' 
  }, 
  { OBJECTID: '788', 
    ID: 'AR0xx', 
    sub_key: '1001', 
    Long_Name: 'buzzz' 
  } 
]; 

var j = subitems.length;
var result = {};
var p;
var sub_key;
var obj;

for (var i=0, iLen = items.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  p = items[i].Name;
  result[p] = [];
  sub_key = items[i].sub_key;

  for (var j=0, jLen=subitems.length; j<jLen; j++) {

    if (subitems[j].sub_key == sub_key) {
      result[p].push(subitems[j].Long_Name);
    }
  }
}

alert(result['95TH PCT']); // bar, baz, buzz
```

#### Edit

Return a single object rather than an array of objects, which I think is what is required.

Comment: worked great! My items & subitems array's were direct copy/paste from console.log, and were generated with the ArcGIS javascript API.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newarray = items.slice(0); // make a copy
addloop: for (var i=0; i<subitems.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<newarray.length; j++)
        if (subitems[i].sub_key == newarray[j].sub_key)
            continue addloop;
    newarray.push(subitems[i]);
}
```

should work. Another solution:

```
Array.prototype.combine = function(a, test) {
    if (typeof test == "function") {
        for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            if (! this.some(test.bind(null, a[i])))
                this.push(a[i]);
    } else {
        for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            if (this.indexOf(a[i]) == -1)
                this.push(a[i]);
    }
    return this;
};

var newarray = items.slice(0).combine(subitems, function(a, b) {
    return a.sub_key == b.sub_key;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this on the train but didn't get to post it, and it looks like a couple of other people posted good answers since, but it might still be helpful so I'll post it anyways

I had a few different things to note:

```
var items = [
    Object { 
        OBJECTID=1,
        Name="COMMAND B", 
        ID="AR0xx",
        sub_key="1000"
    },
    ...
```

- You don't need the word `Object` here, you can just write `{ ... }` and JS knows it's an object.
- Within an object, you need `:` instead of `=`
- It's not required, but putting the key in quotes is good practice because some keys won't work otherwise.

So it should look like this:

```
var items = [
    { 
        "OBJECTID": 1,
        "Name": "COMMAND B", 
        "ID": "AR0xx",
        "sub_key": "1000"
    },
    ...
```

Next up, I'm not completely clear on what you're doing with your `data` array in the second block, but it looks like you're overriding it with an empty array in the third block.

Also, I think you may be confusing `Objects` and `Arrays` somewhat. http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/ has a good overview of the differences, but here's some key points:

- `Array` is a subclass of `Object`
- `Array` values always have numeric indexes, not string keys
- `push()` is a method of `Array` not `Object`

Next up, your loop. `for .. in` style loops do work on arrays, but they're not generally recommended because they can also hit keys that were added to the underlying `Object`. `forEach` is my favorite but it's not always available in older browsers without a library such as  [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/).

`for(var i=0, len=MyArray.length; i<len; i++) {...}` is the other option that you'll see very commonly because it covers all of the array items but does not have the possibility of hitting the underlying object.

But, since Bergi and RobG both have good loops, I'll stop here.